# Alter all Webform's form with hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter

Tags: 7, webforms

What is the base `form_id` for *Webform*'s forms to use in `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()`?

My website will have lots of Webforms and I'm looking the proper way to alter this huge amount of forms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the base form is **webform_client_form** and hook look like

> HOOK_form_webform_client_form_alter

or if using HOOK_form_alter we need statement as

```
if (strstr($form_id, 'webform_client_form_')) {
  //our code for all webforms
}
```